# How can I write my own 'filesystem' within Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I've recalled using little 'filesystems' before that basically provided an interface to something else. For example, I believe there was a GMail filesystem that created an entry in My Computer and could be used like any other drive on your local computer. How can I go about implementing something like this in C++?
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links guys. I wasn't being literal with the term filesystem, which is why I enclosed it in quotations. It was just the best analogy for me in this situation. Please excuse my lack of terminology.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.github.io/). It's like FUSE, except for Windows. I think there are certain limitations to namespace extensions, like they cannot be accessed from the command line, but I'm really not sure as of now.

Comment: Dokan really is like FUSE. Basically: someone took the effort of writing the messy IFS kernel-mode code for you, and let you access it from user mode.

Answer (score 10):

Writing an actual file-system involves writing a *driver*; which means kernel-mode code (scary stuff) and <del>paying for</del> getting the [IFS DDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/ifskit/default.mspx). (edit: looks like they don't charge for it anymore)

What you probably want is a “namespace extension”.
Try this: [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Namespace Extensions - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/namespcextguide1.aspx)

Comment: Not really :) It was like... first Google result.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a starting point to extending NTFS in the way that the GMail filesystem used to do: [Windows NT reparse points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point).

Answer (score 1):

The GMail Filesystem is just the name given; it is not any filesystem as such.  It is just a namespace extension for Windows Explorer that links with the GMail account of yours!

I dont know exactly what you are trying to do, but in anyway, I believe, the following link will be of some use to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference: virtual drives can be created using our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) product, which is a supported, documented and maintained solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of this too, perhaps some example code ? (email me if i forget plz ;p doin sdk now)

I'm thinking of a similar filesystem that would plug in as a driver and allow dynamic 'soft raid' on larger files mostly by putting them on more than one disk, perhaps some compression options and 'smart' filters to toggle usage in high disk space low usage and other situations more effectively, with status controls and indicators as a normalish program too

Seems like I would load the driver kit,
then i want the file writing event, and am mostly replacing fopen and similar functions automatically as an intermediate driver with a little windows network driver experience

I also heard good things about developing on a virtual machine for less crashing and more debugging

Also perhaps more metainfo on some or all files, including files in special folders with options too, including maybe both fast and simple (obfuscated and/or symmetic key) encryption options on folder, specified, all, letter, etc, or whatever, or the slower version and maybe integrated and optional (also profitable) online cvs-like diff style backups that mostly target changes to hot files for online backup at intervals and prices, mostly perhaps with matching keyboard events and might even be useful as simply a keylogging online backup service that is reasonably secure too

while avoiding common files like windows files or the normal stuff in the 'programs' directory that can be copied easily with pirate tools, unlike all of your documents.