# Is it possible to create a virtual file in Windows? (i.e. FUSE interface)

Tags: windows, fuse

How hard is it to create a virtual file of sorts on Windows that can add functionality to read/write calls?

For instance, ideally I'd want to create a file then attach an event handler so whenever the file is read, the read call blocks and code is ran to fetch data, that data is populated into the file, then the data is sent to the program requesting the read.

From what I understand this is close to how FUSE works, but there doesn't seem to be a FUSE implementation in Windows.  Capturing the open/read/write is really all I need if there is a way to do that.

Comment: See [
How can I write my own 'filesystem' within Windows?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962624/how-can-i-write-my-own-filesystem-within-windows)

Comment: http://dokan-dev.net/en/   (Disclaimer: I found Dokan to somewhat work, but be highly unstable.  But I have heard of production code shipping on it.)